# Qfield viewing features in layer without geometry

Tags: attribute-table, qfield, mobile-gis, portable-gis

I created Qfield project that includes layer without geometry. I can successfully create new features but couldnt find a way to edit or view created features on mobile device. I looked through documentation but could not find anything about it.

Since features in layers with geometry can be viewed by selecting on the map i presume viewing features without geometry is not (yet) possible within Qfield. Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [search functionality](https://www.qfield.org/docs/project-management/configure-search.html) in QField to get access to features without geometry and edit or delete them.

Comment: This worked. Before packaging the project i had to set display name under layer properties. I used COALESCE( ) listing all column names.Side note: It seems typing tripple space can be used to search for all features within layer.

Comment: `CONCAT()` is your friend in this scenario, then you don't have to type `COALESCE` so many times. I didn't know about the triple space, interesting "feature" :)